# How do I get .bat files to run instead of being opened with Notepad?

Tags: windows-vista, file-association

My Vista machine is opening `.bat` files with Notepad. How do I get it to run the `.bat` files instead? What application do I assign `.bat` files to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you go to Explorer, and go to **Tools**, **Options**, and click the **File Types** tab, you can scroll down and see .BAT. Associate it with **cmd.exe**.